# Xcode 11 backward compatibility: "UIWindowScene is only available in iOS 13 or newer"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11

In Xcode 11, I created a new app project from the Single View App template. I want this app to run in iOS 12 as well as iOS 13. But when I switch the deployment target to iOS 12, I got a lot of error messages like this one:

> UIWindowScene is only available in iOS 13 or newer

What should I do?

Comment: For anyone looking for an updated "Single View App" Xcode template that supports iOS 12 and 13 as well as supporting either a storyboard or an all-code user interface, see https://github.com/rmaddy/XcodeTemplates.

Comment: I think Apple developer should learn from Google Android Studio a lot of thing.  Android studio allow user select minSDK first , before code template generating is perform.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The template in Xcode 11 uses a scene delegate. Scene delegates and the related classes are new in iOS 13; they don't exist in iOS 12 and before, and the launch process is different.

To make a project generated from an Xcode 11 app template backward compatible, you need to mark the entire SceneDelegate class, and any methods in the AppDelegate class that refer to UISceneSession, as `@available(iOS 13.0, *)`.

You also need to declare a `window` property in the AppDelegate class (if you don't do that, the app will run and launch but the screen will be black):

```
var window : UIWindow?
```

The result is that when this app runs in iOS 13, the scene delegate has the `window`, but when it runs in iOS 12 or before, the app delegate has the `window` — and your other code may then need to take account of *that* in order to be backward compatible.

Comment: Your solution is a good one. That said, would it make sense to simply delete `SceneDelegate` if your only goal is to support iOS 12? Adding `var window : UIWindow?` back to `AppDelegate` is still necessary of course. To fix the other errors, you would also need to remove the generated "UISceneSession Lifecycle" methods from `AppDelegate` and the `UIApplicationSceneManifest` key / value from `Info.plist`. Maybe there are other reasons to keep `SceneDelegate` though?

Comment: @JWK You must use UIWindowScene going forward. That’s why it’s in the template.

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarifying. Any chance you can't point me to where that's documented? I understood scenes to be opt in, and only required to display multiple copies of an app’s UI: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_scenes/specifying_the_scenes_your_app_supports.

Comment: Well there's lots of WWDC videos about it.

Comment: I did see the April 2020 requirement from Session 224. I thought it pertained to making adaptive apps that support split screen multitasking as opposed to explicitly requiring multiple copy support. I may have misunderstood.

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about. I'm not saying multiple copy support is _required_. I'm saying that window scenes are the new app architecture going forward, even if there is only one scene.

Comment: Sure. Just trying to confirm where specifically I can learn more about scenes being required. The April 2020 requirement came to mind from my WWDC viewing. Didn’t mean to imply that’s what you were saying :)

Comment: https://sarunw.com/tips/create-new-ios12-project-in-xcode11/ - this tutorial may help someone.

Comment: can you put a example for put @available(iOS 13.0, *) in UISceneSession

Comment: @x-rw Sketch at https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch01p004appWithoutStoryboard2/bk2ch01p004appWithoutStoryboard

Answer (score 62):

Could you please add this line code like the following

**STEP1:-**

**@available out the SceneDelegate.swift**

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

//...

}
```

**STEP2:-**

**@available out some methods in AppDelegate.swift**

```
// AppDelegate.swift

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
    return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    // Called when the user discards a scene session.
    // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
    // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
}
```

**STEP3:-**

You should declare **window** property in AppDelegate.swift file
 like *var window: UIWindow?*

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

     var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

Comment: but how this will work with programmatic implementation? (without Storyboard)

Comment: @HattoriHanzō without storyboard : 

We can declare in AppDelegate 

    var window: UIWindow?
    var rootViewController:ViewController!

And In didFinishLaunching method add these lines :

        rootViewController = ViewController()
        
        self.window = UIWindow.init()
        self.window?.bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
        self.window?.backgroundColor = .white
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()