# Xcode 11 > change deployment target to iOS 12, Error with AppDelegate window.rootViewController access

Tags: ios, ios13, xcode11

While developing iOS application in Xcode 11 I've changed deployment target to iOS 12. So all this code with SceneDelegate and scene sessions that is for new multi-window support is now unavailable. So I've commented it out totally.

But no I have such bug

> There is no scene delegate set. A scene delegate class must be specified to use a main storyboard file.

And when I try to access self.window!.rootViewController to attach some initial UIViewController (it is also defined in Main.storyboard with isInitial attribute checked)

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916948/xcode-11-backward-compatibility-uiwindowscene-is-only-available-in-ios-13-or-n